# $R$ module homomorphisms between two modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $k$ be a field. Is the only $R=k[x,y]$ module homomorphism $(k[x,y]/(x,y))^2 \to (x,y)/(x,y)^2$ given by the zero map? Also, is $(x,y)/(x,y)^2 \cong R/(x,y)$?

If I had to give an attempt for this, I would say it is true because $$\phi(x,0)=x\phi(1,0)=0$$
and $$\phi(0,x)=x\phi(0,1)=0$$

I think? Or is this a lousy attempt?

What about $k[x,y]/(x,y) \to (k[x,y]/(x,y))^2$ are there a plethora of homomorphisms? The only ones I can think of are $0$ and inclusions. Would any others be determines solely by homomorphism $k[x,y]/(x,y) \to k[x,y]/(x,y)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No and no, to the questions in the first line.

1. $k[x,y]/(x,y)\cong k$, so we can define a map by sending $(p,0)\mapsto p\cdot(ax+by)$ and $(0,q)\mapsto q\cdot(cx+dy)$ for any $a,b,c,d,p,q\in k$. Each of these maps are $R$-linear, and any such map is non-zero as long as $a,b,c,d$ are not all zero.
2. $(x,y)/(x,y)^2\cong k\langle x,y\rangle$, where the RHS is the $k$-vector space on the basis $\{x,y\}$. To see this, the polynomials in $(x,y)$ are exactly those with zero constant term, and any two such polynomials with the same linear term agree up to an element of $(x,y)^2=(x^2,xy,y^2)$ which consists of all polynomials with zero constant and linear terms. As $k[x,y]/(x,y)$ and $(x,y)/(x,y)^2$ have different dimensions as $k$-vector spaces, they cannot be isomorphic.

As for the third question at the end, the above should give you the tools to work on that too. You're asking about maps $k\to k^2$, and any such map is determined by the vector which is the image of $1\in k$.